# How can I cut a plane properly with 2D text shapes in three.js?

Tags: text, three.js, shapes

Many text characters have internal holes (like a,b,d,e,g,o,p,q,0,4,6,8,9 etc). If I take their 2D shapes and use them to cut holes on a flat shape, only the outline of those shapes will be cut and the center hole of each character won't remain on the flat shape.

Is there a solution to cut the plane properly using text shapes?
Note that I'm looking for a native three.js solution with 2D text shapes, NOT use a library and extruded 3D text which would be far less efficient.

example main code: 2D text shapes cutting a rectangle shape:

```
// text shapes
var message = "example";
var textshapes = font.generateShapes( message, 100, 2 );

// rectangle shape
var width = 800, height = 300, x = -130, y = -110;    
var rectShape = new THREE.Shape();
rectShape.moveTo( x, y );
rectShape.lineTo( x, y+height );
rectShape.lineTo( x+width, y+height );
rectShape.lineTo( x+width, y );
rectShape.lineTo( x, y );

//cut rectangle shape with the message's text shapes
var tslen = textshapes.length;
for (i=0; i<tslen; i++){
    rectShape.holes.push( textshapes[i] );
}

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(rectShape);
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the approach, using `.merge()`. I can't say, that this is the best solution (as it was made from a scratch just now), but, at least, it gives an acceptable result:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg");
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 800);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x101010);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {
  // text shapes
  var message = "example8";
  var textshapes = font.generateShapes(message, 100, 2);

  // rectangle shape
  var width = 875,
    height = 300,
    x = -130,
    y = -110;
  var rectShape = new THREE.Shape();
  rectShape.moveTo(x, y);
  rectShape.lineTo(x, y + height);
  rectShape.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
  rectShape.lineTo(x + width, y);
  rectShape.lineTo(x, y);

  //cut rectangle shape with the message's text shapes
  var tslen = textshapes.length;
  for (i = 0; i < tslen; i++) {
    rectShape.holes.push(textshapes[i]);
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(rectShape);

  for (let i = 0; i < tslen; i++) {
    let letter = textshapes[i];
    if (letter.holes && letter.holes.length > 0) {
      for (let j = 0; j < letter.holes.length; j++) {
        // here we make geometries from holes and merge them with the main geometry
        let hole = letter.holes[j];
        let pts = hole.getPoints();

        let innerShape = new THREE.Shape(pts);
        let innerGeom = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(innerShape);
        geometry.merge(innerGeom);
      }
    }
  }

  geometry.center();

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "aqua",
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  }));
  scene.add(mesh);
});

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

[Reference](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/35ae830a7c4544582ed2759e5b18c5d6ef37c6d9/examples/webgl_geometry_text_shapes.html#L94)

Comment: It works, while it stays 2D and native, so it gets my vote. Quick and awesome, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Three csg module by stemkoski. Not sure why you want to avoid "libraries" since three is pretty modular and attempts to keep esoteric features like you are describing, out of its core. Hth!

Comment: Do you really think it's worth to be an answer, not a comment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?